# Select Strings from text file - Power Shell

Tags: text, comparison

my txt file looks like this:

```
Op          : BootResponse
HType       : Ethernet
HLen        : 6
Hops        : 0
Secs        : 0
Flags       : {Broadcast}
CIAddr      : 0.0.0.0
YIAddr      : 192.168.0.27
SIAddr      : 192.168.0.1
GIAddr      : 0.0.0.0
SName       : 
File        : smsboot\PS101\x86\pxe.cpm

Op          : BootResponse
HType       : Ethernet
HLen        : 6
Hops        : 0
Secs        : 0
Flags       : {Broadcast}
CIAddr      : 0.0.0.0
YIAddr      : 192.168.0.28
SIAddr      : 192.168.0.1
GIAddr      : 0.0.0.0
SName       : 
File        : 

and so on
```

In my script I want to check if the IP Address of "SIAddr" equals 192.168.0.27 and I want to check if the **according File** entry contains "smsboot"

So the output should be in this case: "The SIAddr equals 192.168.0.27 and the File contains smsboot"

How can I filter the txt file like this?

I tried

```
$path = "C:\temp\boot.txt"

$smsboot = Select-String -Path $path -Pattern "smsboot"

if ($smsboot -ne $null) { Write-Host "File contains smsboot"}
else {Write-Host "File does not contain smsboot"}
```

That works. But it does not make sure that the file entry belongs to the SIAddr. And how can I get the SIAddr and compare it?

THANKS!